# Extract all text & tags between two heading tags (<h3>) with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

[This page](https://www.karger.com/Journal/EditorialBoard/223997) shows six sections listing people between `<h3>` tags.

How can I use XPath to select these six sections separately (using `rvest`), perhaps into a nested list? My goal is to later `lapply` through these six sections to fetch the people's names and affiliations (separated by section).

The HTML isn't so well-structured, i.e. not every text is located within specific tags. An example:

```
<h3>Editor-in-Chief</h3>
Claudio Ronco &ndash; <i>St. Bartolo Hospital</i>, Vicenza, Italy<br />
<br />
<h3>Clinical Engineering</h3>
William R. Clark &ndash; <i>Purdue University</i>, West Lafayette, IN, USA<br />
Hideyuki Kawanashi &ndash; <i>Tsuchiya General Hospital</i>, Hiroshima, Japan<br />
```

I access the site with the following code:

```
journal_url <- "https://www.karger.com/Journal/EditorialBoard/223997"
webpage <- rvest::html_session(journal_url,
                  httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.672.2 Safari/534.20"))

webpage <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, css = '#editorialboard')
```

I tried various XPaths to extract the six sections with `html_nodes` into a nested list of six lists, but none of them work properly:

```
# this gives me a list of 190 (instead of 6) elements, leaving out the text between <i> and </i>
webpage <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, xpath = '//text()[preceding-sibling::h3 and following-sibling::h3]')

# this gives me a list of 190 (instead of 6) elements, leaving out text that are not between tags
webpage <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, xpath = '//*[preceding-sibling::h3 and following-sibling::h3]')

# error "VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'logical'"
webpage <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, xpath = '//* and text()[preceding-sibling::h3 and following-sibling::h3]')

# this gives me a list of 274 (instead of 6) elements
webpage <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, xpath = '//text()[preceding-sibling::h3]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you ok with an ugly solution that does not use XPath? I don't think you can get a nested list from the structure of this website... But I am not very experienced in xpath.

I first got the headings, divided the raw text using the heading names and then, within each group, divided the members using '\n' as a separator.

```
journal_url <- "https://www.karger.com/Journal/EditorialBoard/223997"

webpage <- read_html(journal_url) %>% html_node(css = '#editorialboard')

# get h3 headings
headings <- webpage %>% html_nodes('h3') %>% html_text()

# get raw text
raw.text <- webpage %>% html_text()

# split raw text on h3 headings and put in a list
list.members <- list()
raw.text.2 <- raw.text
for (h in headings) {
  # split on headings
  b <- strsplit(raw.text.2, h, fixed=TRUE)
  # split members using \n as separator
  c <- strsplit(b[[1]][1], '\n', fixed=TRUE)
  # clean empty elements from vector
  c <- list(c[[1]][c[[1]] != ""])
  # add vector of member to list
  list.members <- c(list.members, c)
  # update text
  raw.text.2 <- b[[1]][2]
}
# remove first element of main list
list.members <- list.members[2:length(list.members)]
# add final segment of raw.text to list
c <- strsplit(raw.text.2, '\n', fixed=TRUE)
c <- list(c[[1]][c[[1]] != ""])
list.members <- c(list.members, c)
# add names to list
names(list.members) <- headings
```

Then you get a list of the groups and each element of the list is a vector with strings for each member (using all info)

```
> list.members$`Editor-in-Chief`
[1] "Claudio Ronco – St. Bartolo Hospital, Vicenza, Italy"
> list.members$`Clinical Engineering`
 [1] "William R. Clark – Purdue University, West Lafayette, IN, USA"                     
 [2] "Hideyuki Kawanashi – Tsuchiya General Hospital, Hiroshima, Japan"                  
 [3] "Tadayuki Kawasaki – Mobara Clinic, Mobara City, Japan"                             
 [4] "Jeongchul Kim – Wake Forest School of Medicine, Winston-Salem, NC, USA"            
 [5] "Anna Lorenzin – International Renal Research Institute of Vicenza, Vicenza, Italy" 
 [6] "Ikuto Masakane – Honcho Yabuki Clinic, Yamagata City, Japan"                       
 [7] "Michio Mineshima – Tokyo Women's Medical University, Tokyo, Japan"                 
 [8] "Tomotaka Naramura – Kurashiki University of Science and the Arts, Kurashiki, Japan"
 [9] "Mauro Neri – International Renal Research Institute of Vicenza, Vicenza, Italy"    
[10] "Masanori Shibata – Koujukai Rehabilitation Hospital, Nagoya City, Japan"           
[11] "Yoshihiro Tange – Kyushu University of Health and Welfare, Nobeoka-City, Japan"    
[12] "Yoshiaki Takemoto – Osaka City University, Osaka City, Japan"
```

Comment: That's wonderful, it works very well, thank you! And yes, I am okay with "ugly" solutions - - I think this is inevitable with webscraping :-)

Comment: Great! You're welcome. I noticed a small typo in my code (when I add final segment of raw.text to list). I corrected it, but it was not changing the results.